# How do I replace a range of characters in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, replace

With Ruby, how do I replace a range of characters in a string?  For instance, given teh string

```
hellothere
```

If I want to replace characters at index positions two through five inclusive with "#" to result in a string

```
he####here
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get a string range and replace it by setting the new character multiplied for the last index plus 1 less the first index:

```
def replace_in_string(str, replace, start, finish)
  str[start..finish] = replace * (finish + 1 - start)
  str
end

p replace_in_string 'hellothere', '#', 2, 5
# "he####here"
```

Comment: Soudns like a good idea ... how exactly would I add it to the String class?

Comment: @Natalia Note that just because you can, doesn't mean you should. Adding methods to core classes is **strongly** discouraged.

Comment: @SebastianPalma, thanks for the edit.  What is the project path I shoudl use for adding to the String clsas (e.g. lib/string.rb or something like that?)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the characters directly into a slice of the string like this:

```
s = 'hellothere'      # Initial string
s[2..5] = '####'      # Assign desired string to the desired Range 2..5
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**